# Onclick event unable to pass into mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to send this into my database with PHP:

```
 <a class="content_link" href="http://www.example.com" title="Example" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">  </a>
```

If I delete "onclick" it works, but if I leave it, I get an error saying "Chrome detected unusual code on this page and blocked it to protect your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, and credit cards)." FYI, the onclick="trackOutboundLink is tracking code for Google Tag Manager.

I guess that the question lies in passing Javascript event handlers through mysql. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try in another web browsers like firefox

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/UrsSOYWITe0

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are missing the function you must place it in the head to define `trackOutboundLink` function

place this code in `head` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackOutboundLink(url){
     $.ajax({
         url: "post.php", 
         dataType: "html",
         type: 'POST', //I want a type as POST
         data: "url="+url, 
         success: function(data){ 
            alert("sucess");
         }
      });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Rtra.  I'm sending this information with a form into my database, so it's in a string form.  I don't think I'd need to include this script just for this data to be entered into my database.  I will need to include this script on my page when I pull this data onto my website, though.

Comment: OK than you require an ajax function into it so it will post data to your database

Comment: @Adam i have edited the code now you can customize your php file and location according to it `post.php`